# Joining two data fields

Tags: php, arrays, json, getjson

The `$datax` contains numbers `1` and `2` (see `json` output), however it must contain entries similar to `1 / XXX`, `2 / XXX`, etc. (`$datax[] = $row['solution_id'] + " / " + $row['Type'];`)

Where is the error?

```
<?php
include_once 'include/connect_db.php';

$query="SELECT A.solution_id, A.Type,A.Time2,B.Time1 
           FROM Table1 A 
           INNER JOIN Table2 B 
           ON A.Type=B.Type;";

$result=ejecutar_query($query);

$datax = array();
$datay1 = array();
$datay2 = array();

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $datax[] = $row['solution_id'] + " / " + $row['Type'];
    $datay1[] = $row['Time1'];
    $datay2[] = $row['Time2'];
}

echo json_encode(array('x' => $datax, 'y1' => $datay1, 'y2' => $datay2));
die();

?>
```

**JSON**

> {"x":[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],"y1":["2013-05-29 17:24:00","2013-05-29
>   17:24:00","2013-05-29 17:22:00","2013-05-29 17:22:00","2013-05-29
>   17:18:00","2013-05-29 17:18:00","2013-05-29 17:16:00","2013-05-29
>   17:16:00","2013-05-29 17:11:00","2013-05-29 17:11:00","2013-05-29
>   17:11:00","2013-05-29 17:11:00"],"y2":["2013-05-29
>   17:56:26","2013-05-29 18:03:38","2013-05-29 17:48:12","2013-05-29
>   17:42:53","2013-05-29 17:10:32","2013-05-29 17:52:08","2013-05-29
>   17:08:00","2013-05-29 17:10:18","2013-05-29 17:42:53","2013-05-29
>   17:06:12","2013-05-29 17:05:39","2013-05-29 18:09:00"]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, `.` is the concatenation operator

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $datax[] = $row['solution_id'] . " / " . $row['Type'];
    $datay1[] = $row['Time1'];
    $datay2[] = $row['Time2'];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the dot operator `.` in php. So `$row['solution_id'] . " / " . $row['Type']` will help.